# Entity Framework 6 datetime issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datetime

There seems to be an evident problem when capturing user input from the front end (view) to the back end (Controller) pertaining to datetime formats.

I have looked all over and cant find any solution to the problem i am observing.I have datetime stored in the database.My issue arises when i insert a format of a datetime in the text input (manually and not with a datepicker) that it cant seem to post as it asks for an appropriate format.

When i do select an appropriate format,the application crashes and it cant parse the format.Is there any articles that may help me achieve or understand how the datetime formats and EntityFramework work?

Comment: c# does not store display format for object of type `DateTime`. you should pass a `DateTime` object from your view to the controler (meaning that you need to use one of the `DateTime` parse methods inside your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

Model

```
[Display(Name = "Startdate")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime StartedAt { get; set; }
```

View

```
if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
    $('input[type=date]').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});}
```

Comment: this kinda works however i cant seem to save that format with time,its throwing a cast error as i am trying to parse it

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a problem in neither EF nor database. Datetime is stored as datetime in a database and not in any particular string format. When you are using text for the input, it is your responsibility to convert it to a valid datetime value. Consider 1/2/2015 as a string. Can you tell what date is it? No you can't. It might be Jan 2nd, 2015 or Feb 1st, 2015. Or consider 15/1/2015. It is a valid date as Jan 15th, 2015 for a machine using one of the European cultures but would be an invalid date fro the USA culture. You would have prevented the problem from the start if you have used a DateTimePicker which returns a DateTime value rather than a string.
You can convert a string to a datetime like this:

```
DateTime x;
DateTime? valueToSendToDatabase = DateTime.TryParse(txtDatetime.Text,
         CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
         DateTimeStyles.None, 
         out x)
         ? x
         : (DateTime?)null;
```

Comment: This is more or ldss clear, but does not tell us how to work with datetime in multi-language  environment.. do you have a link to some tutorial?

Comment: What part is not clear? Instead of CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, you can use any CultureInfo you want to. CurrentCulture is the easy way.

Comment: I mean, it would be interesting to get a generic solution of using DateTime  which uses "Format" attribute (check the question).

Comment: You can use ParseExact if you wanted to. Or to make it easy use a DateTimePicker from the start.

Comment: cool,will parse the string.Will i have to parse it just before i save? i also need a datepicker with time to send it to the controller.anyone have any good recommendations? @CetinBasoz

Comment: The parsing also helped me here.Thanks everyone